How to skip before_action for all rails specs
In my controller i have several before_actions. But I need to skip the specific before_action for all tests. I can't do this in every test. This should be done at the global level, perhaps in spec_helper or rails_helper.
For example:
class SomeController < BaseController
  before_action :some_before_action

Running every test some_before_action should be ignored

"I need to skip the specific before_action for all tests" – why? Can you give some more context?

@Stefan coz code in this some_before_action is temporaty and should not be tested. But all my tests currently does not work coz they invoke this action

Maybe before_action :some_before_action, unless: -> { Rails.env.test? }, but you should probably fix the cause of the problem, i.e. try to get your tests running with the action instead of skipping it.

An easy approach to disable this before_action in all our tests might be adding this line to your spec/rails_helper.rb:
config.before(:all) do
  allow_any_instance_of(SomeController)
    .to receive(:some_before_action)
    .and_return(true)
end

I recommend this only as a temporary solution, for example, during a refactoring, but not permanently. When you find yourself using this permanently, then a refactoring of the controller and the before_action is certainly the better option.

Ok, simple solution was to add before_action :some_before_action unless Rails.env.test? since it temporaty code

before_action :some_before_action unless Rails.env.test? is not the same as before_action :some_before_action, unless: Rails.env.test?.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
